# finding records that have dates that fall before the date 7 days from now. using datetime format

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find records based on the current date. One of the queries I am trying to do is find any record that falls within 7 days of the current date. this is what I have

```
WHERE `Project`.`delivery_deadline` <= 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)' 
GROUP BY `Project`.`id` 
LIMIT 20
```

This isn't working of course. what exactly am I doing wrong. 
delivery_deadline is datetime format not date format

Comment: what on the world make you put DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) in single quotes ?

Comment: Why are you doing `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: As DATE_SUB is a function, and not a value, you should remove the quotes. I don't know if that's sufficient to solve your problem, but you should include information on your table structure aswell. We don't know what type your date column is. Datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not you write:

```
WHERE `Project`.`delivery_deadline` >= 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
```

**edit**

The correct solution is:

```
WHERE Project.delivery_deadline between now() and date_add(now() ,interval 7 day)
```

Comment: you are correct. and I have it like that now but its still not exactly doing what I want it to do. if you look at the comments above. I am trying to get all records that have a delivery deadline that falls anytime before the date 7 days from now. I created a date that went beyond the 13th of this month and it still showed. delivery_deadline is also in datetime format, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Is it not better to use `WHERE Project.delivery_deadline between now() and date_add(now() ,interval 7 day)` then ?

Comment: It worked for me. I am refering to `date_add(now() ,interval 7 day)` i used this and it worked perfectly. I am also using datetime and I am not sure if CURDATE() works well with datetime formats

Comment: I tested the query before handing it over to you. I found that it worked for the purpose you wanted. If Gianlucas answer helped you, that's good! But his answer, as it stands now, is wrong. So you should edit it and correct it so that it won't confuse other people with the same question!

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE `Project`.`delivery_deadline` <= 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)' 
GROUP BY `Project`.`id` 
LIMIT 20
```

compares your deadline against the string `'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)'`, whereas

```
WHERE `Project`.`delivery_deadline` <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY `Project`.`id` 
LIMIT 20
```

compares it against the result of `DATE_SUB()`, which could be what you want.

Comment: ... and I guess it should be `>=` instead of `<=`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I allways try to keep as much of the OQ intact as possible, even if I don't like the formating myself ;-)

Comment: @bfavaretto I understood the OQ was to find deadlines approaching (1 Week) or past, which would translate to `<=`

Comment: @EugenRieck: well, I took the liberty and modified the original post. You can follow me :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If YOU are not lazy, then I may not be as well

Comment: @EugenRieck, nevermind, I'm confused. What I understand from the query is that it will select rows where `delivery_deadline` is 7 days ago, or earlier. I'm not sure if that's what the OQ wants.

Comment: What I want is any record that has a deadline that falls anytime before the date 7 days from now. so any deadline that falls before 1/13/12

Comment: or to go further, any deadline that falls between the current date and the date 7 days from now.

Comment: its in datetime format so i dont know if that has anything to do with it

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your query to look like this. That'll give you your desired result:

```
WHERE `Project`.`delivery_deadline` >= CURDATE() 
AND `Project`.`delivery_deadline` <= (CURDATE() + 7)
GROUP BY `Project`.`id` 
LIMIT 20
```

A project that ends earliest today or no later than 7 days from today.

Comment: You don't quote functions in mysql. And you shouldn't quote integers either, unless they're posted in a varchar/text field. Try editing your query the way i suggested and see if it works.