# Trying to find a record between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Queries looks like this

```
WHERE `Project`.`user_id` = 9 
  AND `Project`.`project_status` = 1 
  AND `Project`.`project_type_id` = 4
  AND `Project`.`approval_date` >= '01/08/2012' 
  AND `Project`.`approval_date` <= '01/12/2012'
```

I do have a record that matches this criteria, I actually created the query based on one of the records but it does not return. I really do not want to use the `BETWEEN` because the application can either use start date or end date

Comment: what data type are you using for the 'approval_date' field

Comment: Try applying each search criteria one by one until no rows are returned, that will help find the problem. It's hard to answer your question without some sample data.

Comment: @kissmyface - based on OP's previous questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764015/finding-records-that-have-dates-that-fall-before-the-date-7-days-from-now - it's a datetime column

Comment: Under what locale MySQL server is running? It could be an issue if MySQL is treating date as 'dd/mm/yyyy' while you are relying on 'mm/dd/yyyy' or visa versa

Answer (score 2):

You should convert '01/08/2012' and '01/12/2012' to MySQL date/time values using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

e.g.

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: that may work. only problem is I need to format to datetime I tried tweeking what you said but it didnt work. `Project.project_type_id = 4 AND Project.approval_date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2012','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND Project.approval_date <= STR_TO_DATE('01/26/2012','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: You have to define the format mask to match the actual format of your date string

Answer (score 1):

Well that's really only part of the query -- any, "between" works differently than you imply - here's an excerpt from the MySQL manual:

> •expr BETWEEN min AND max  If expr is greater than or equal to min and
>   expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it
>   returns 0. This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr
>   <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type. Otherwise type
>   conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section
>   11.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

All that aside what is the datatype of the "approval_date" column?

Comment: I think my problem maybe that I am comparing a date formatted string with a datetime formatted column. I need to probably first convert my string to datetime. see the comment I made below on kissmyface response

Answer (score 1):

This looks as if it should work on first glance, however the values you have supplied **are not valid datetimes**. Try this instead

```
WHERE `Project`.`user_id` = 9 
AND `Project`.`project_status` = 1 
AND `Project`.`project_type_id` = 4
AND `Project`.`approval_date` >= '2012-01-08 00:00:00' 
AND `Project`.`approval_date` <= '2012-01-12 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Ok, that is what I would like. Is it possible to use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert to datetime format ?? cause I would like to factor in the time.

Comment: I tried using php date() to format the date. `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start);` I am using JQUERY to get the date. the value $start =  01/02/2012. for some reason I am getting the following error `A non well formed numeric value encountered` and php is returning the formatted date of ` `1969-12-31 19:00:01`

Comment: Are you using jquery UI datepicker by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

you can still use `BETWEEN`

```
WHERE `Project`.`user_id` = 9 
AND `Project`.`project_status` = 1 
AND `Project`.`project_type_id` = 4
AND (`Project`.`approval_date` BETWEEN '2012-01-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-12 23:59:59')
```

Comment: I can I still use the between when sometimes the end date or the start date is not availible.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was getting the string to format into datetime. kissmyface was correct on just structuring it correctly so mysql could understand. So I used php to convert it before sending it out.

```
"Project.approval_date >= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($start))."'";
"Project.approval_date <= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($end))."'";
```

this was pretty much my solution. unless anyone knows away to do the exact same thing on mysql side.